# Selecting N rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Following query will return 1-10 in 10 rows.

```
DECLARE @Range AS INT = 10

;WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT TOP (@Range) Duration = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY OBJECT_ID)
    FROM sys.all_columns
    ORDER BY [Object_id]
)
SELECT Duration from CTE
```

But when I set @Range as 10000 it returns 7374 rows. Why this query can't return more than 7374 rows.

**UPDATE**

I just found another way to achieve my requirement as following

```
DECLARE @start INT = 1;
DECLARE @end INT = 10;

WITH numbers AS (
    SELECT @start AS number
    UNION ALL
    SELECT number + 1 
    FROM  numbers
    WHERE number < @end
)
SELECT *
FROM numbers
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Without last line of code it breaks with error Maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion and I found this line is specifying 0 for infinite recursion. But this query seems a little slower to me. Is there any faster way???

Comment: Because `sys.all_columns` contains only 7374 rows?

Comment: Thnx @cbranch.. How did i miss it !!!

Comment: See my answer using Itzik Ben-Gan's stacked/cascaded CTE.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As commented earlier, it's because you reached the number of rows of `sys.columns`. Here is another way to generate list of numbers or what others call `Numbers Table` or `Tally Table`.

This uses cascaded `CTE`s and is said to be the fastest way to create a Tally Table:

```
DECLARE @Range AS INT = 7374

;WITH E1(N) AS( -- 10 ^ 1 = 10 rows
    SELECT 1 FROM(VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))t(N)
),
E2(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E1 a CROSS JOIN E1 b), -- 10 ^ 2 = 100 rows
E4(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E2 a CROSS JOIN E2 b), -- 10 ^ 4 = 10,000 rows
E8(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E4 a CROSS JOIN E4 b), -- 10 ^ 8 = 10,000,000 rows
CteTally(N) AS(
    SELECT TOP(@Range) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL))
    FROM E8
)
SELECT * FROM CteTally
```

You could easily add another CTE if you need more than 10,000 rows.

For more information about Tally Table, read this excellent [**article**](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/) by Jeff Moden.

For performance comparisons among ways to generate Tally Tables, read [**this**](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/74118/).

---

Explanation taken from Jeff's [article](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/74118/):

> The CTE called `E1` (as in 10E1 for scientific notation) is nothing
>   more than ten `SELECT 1`'s returned as a single result set.
>
> `E2` does a `CROSS JOIN` of `E1` with itself. That returns a single
>   result set of 10*10 or up to 100 rows. I say "up to" because if the
>   TOP function is 100 or less, the CTE's are "smart" enough to know that
>   it doesn't actually need to go any further and `E4` and `E8` won't
>   even come into play. If the `TOP` has a value of less than 100, not
>   all 100 rows that `E2` is capable of making will be made. It'll always
>   make just enough according to the `TOP` function.
>
> You can follow from there. `E4` is a `CROSS JOIN` of `E2` and will
>   make up to 100*100 or 10,000 rows and `E8` is a `CROSS JOIN` of `E4`
>   which will make more rows than most people will ever need. If you do
>   need more, then just add an `E16` as a `CROSS JOIN` of `E8` and change
>   the final `FROM` clause to `FROM E16`.
>
> What's really amazing about this bad-boy is that is produces **ZERO
>   READS**. Absolutely none, nada, nil.

Comment: Yep, Aaron Bertrand has tested the various techniques for doing this in the series [Generate a set or sequence without loops](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1) and the stacked CTE method (attributed to Itzik Ben-Gan) comes out on top of all the on the fly methods. By [part-2](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-2) with 50,000 rows the recursive CTE can't even be compared on the same graph as other methods as it distorts the scale so much.

Comment: Using sys.all_columns required to read its rows where CTE is not. And the TOP function determines how many joins are required to achieve goal. Am I correct ???

Comment: @FelixPamittan, You'd eventually like to change "FROM E4" to "FROM E8". And: Thank you for this great post!

Comment: @Shnugo: Yeah! Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 3):

One way to generate a large series of numbers would be to use a `cross join` to create a cartesian product between two tables which will generate a set that is `n^2` in size.

**This approach however performs a lot worse than the solution put forward in [the answer by Felix Pamittan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32096374/1175077) and therefore shouldn't be used.**

```
DECLARE @Range AS INT = 10000

;WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT TOP (@Range) Duration = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM sys.all_columns a CROSS JOIN sys.all_columns b
)
SELECT Duration from CTE
```

This would generate a set of 54375876 rows in your case. Instead of generating the rows on the fly you should consider creating a tally table suitable for your needs.

Comment: You can do this recursively if you want to see how effective your processor cooling tech is.

Comment: @EricHauenstein Heh, yeah.

Comment: I found a way to do it with recursion but whats the relation with processor cooling tech @EricHauenstein

Comment: @TanjimRahman, I wouldn't suggest using a recursive CTE for this. As commented by Eric, rCTE puts a high load on your CPU.

Comment: Recursion would indeed be a bad option - a cross join should be much faster and less demanding on the processor.

Comment: Itzik Ben-Gan's cascaded CTE would be better than `CROSS JOIN`. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/74118/

Comment: @FelixPamittan So it would seem - much faster. Comes out at a relative cost of 8% compared to 92% for the cross joins. I think I'll just delete this answer as it's a sub-par solution (although working).

Comment: @jpw, no need to delete it. It's still helpful.

Comment: @FelixPamittan Fair enough. I edited in a link to your answer instead :)

Comment: So lots of discussion done and I have learned that recursion is indeed a bad idea. But here I become a little confused. @FelixPamittan as u said to use cross join is better and as u said Itzik Ben-Gan's cascaded CTE is better. But in Itzik Ben-Gan's cascaded CTE is also using cross joins to produce n^2 rows. Both cases I am seeing cross joins so Where I am gonna gain performance???

Comment: Yes both are using `CROSS JOIN`. The difference is the table used in the `JOIN`. In IBG's method, the CTEs are being joined, while on the classic cross join is using `sys.columns`. Please read the articles on my answer for more information.

Answer (score 0):

when value in variable exceeds value 7374, that doesn't matter. That table has only 7374 rows.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the total number of rows return for your query is 7374. If you can create some tables and run the code, you will see the increase in the number

Answer (score 0):

It is because the maximum number of row are 7374, you can use the master..spt_Values table for that cross join to itself and you would get `6325225` values for your desired `Duration` column.

```
DECLARE @Range AS INT = 10000 

;WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT TOP (@Range) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) Duration
    FROM master..spt_values a cross join master..spt_values b
)
SELECT Duration from CTE
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this function to get running numbers. You can directly use it in FROM (or with JOIN or APPLY...)

**After reading other comments I changed this to the "stacked CTE" approach (thx to Felix)**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetRunningNumbers](@anzahl INT=10000000, @StartAt INT=0)
RETURNS TABLE
AS 
RETURN
WITH E1(N) AS( -- 10 ^ 1 = 10 rows
    SELECT 1 FROM(VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))t(N)
),
E2(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E1 a CROSS JOIN E1 b), -- 10 ^ 2 = 100 rows
E4(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E2 a CROSS JOIN E2 b), -- 10 ^ 4 = 10,000 rows
E8(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E4 a CROSS JOIN E4 b), -- 10 ^ 8 = 10,000,000 rows
CteTally AS(
    SELECT TOP(ISNULL(@anzahl,1000000)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL)) -1 + ISNULL(@StartAt,0) As Nmbr
    FROM E8
)
SELECT * FROM CteTally;
```