# Return missing dates from a list in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Considering the filter:

- Start: 14/09/2015 (Monday)
- End: 20/09/2015 (Sunday)

I have this result from a query from 14/09 until 20/09:

```
╔════════════╦══════════╦══════════════╦═══════════╗
║    Date    ║ Employee ║ EmployeeType ║   Type    ║
╠════════════╬══════════╬══════════════╬═══════════╣
║ 14/09/2015 ║ John     ║ Permanent    ║ Timesheet ║
║ 14/09/2015 ║ Silva    ║ Permanent    ║ Timesheet ║
║ 16/09/2015 ║ John     ║ Permanent    ║ Timesheet ║
║ 17/09/2015 ║ Airn     ║ Casual       ║ Timesheet ║
╚════════════╩══════════╩══════════════╩═══════════╝
```

I need to return all the missing dates if the employee is 'Permanent' and if the day missing is from 'Monday to Friday', as follows:

```
╔════════════╦══════════╦══════════════╦═══════════╗
║    Date    ║ Employee ║ EmployeeType ║   Type    ║
╠════════════╬══════════╬══════════════╬═══════════╣
║ 14/09/2015 ║ John     ║ Permanent    ║ Timesheet ║
║ 14/09/2015 ║ Silva    ║ Permanent    ║ Timesheet ║
║ 15/09/2015 ║ John     ║ Permanent    ║ Missing   ║
║ 15/09/2015 ║ Silva    ║ Permanent    ║ Missing   ║
║ 16/09/2015 ║ John     ║ Permanent    ║ Timesheet ║
║ 16/09/2015 ║ Silva    ║ Permanent    ║ Missing   ║
║ 17/09/2015 ║ John     ║ Permanent    ║ Missing   ║
║ 17/09/2015 ║ Airn     ║ Casual       ║ Timesheet ║
║ 17/09/2015 ║ Silva    ║ Permanent    ║ Missing   ║
║ 18/09/2015 ║ John     ║ Permanent    ║ Missing   ║
║ 18/09/2015 ║ Silva    ║ Permanent    ║ Missing   ║
╚════════════╩══════════╩══════════════╩═══════════╝
```

I don't understand very well the `LEAD` command in SQL Server 2012.

Comment: And what if the employee is not "Permanent"? If this criteria is relevant, please add a row or two to the sample data with non-"Permanent" EmployeeType and show us how the final result should look like.

Comment: Added @VladimirBaranov

Comment: @FelixPamittan Yes, that's correct. Only 'Permanent Employees' will show the Missing Timesheets. And only from Mon-Fri

Comment: Is your sample data correct? Is John-Casual really the same John, the one with Permanent employeetype?

Comment: @FelixPamittan sorry, I fixed now. Also If there is another employee as permanent it should show records missing for him, I will update in the sample.

Comment: @RogerOliveira, yes, please, add another permanent employee to the data, just to clarify. Also, Would you expect to see a row for 17/09/2015 for John in the result?

Comment: @VladimirBaranov yes, you guys are a legend, I added the missing one for John on the 17th..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [**Tally Table**](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/) to build the dates from `@start` and `@end` and `CROSS JOIN` it with your table to get the missing dates.

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e8659/1/0)

```
DECLARE @start  DATE = '20150914',
        @end    DATE = '20150920'

;WITH E1(N) AS(
    SELECT 1 FROM(VALUES
        (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1)
    )t(N)
),
E2(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E1 a CROSS JOIN E1 b),
E4(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E2 a CROSS JOIN E2 b),
Tally(N) AS(
    SELECT TOP(DATEDIFF(DAY, @start, @end))
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM E4
),
CteDates(dt) AS(
    SELECT  DATEADD(DAY, N-1, @start) FROM Tally
),
CteEmployee AS(
    SELECT DISTINCT Employee, EmployeeType 
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE EmployeeType = 'Permanent'
)
SELECT
    Date = d.dt,
    e.Employee,
    e.EmployeeType,
    Type = ISNULL(yt.Type, 'Missing')
FROM CteEmployee e
CROSS JOIN CteDates d
LEFT JOIN yourTable yt
    ON e.Employee = yt.Employee
    AND d.dt = yt.Date
WHERE
    ((DATEPART(dw, d.dt) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7) NOT IN (0, 1)

UNION ALL

SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE EmployeeType = 'Casual'
ORDER BY Date, e.Employee
```

---

The `WHERE` clause

```
((DATEPART(dw, d.dt) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7) NOT IN (0, 1)
```

excludes weekends regardless of `@@DATEFIRST`.

- [Explanation on Tally Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32096103/selecting-n-rows-in-sql-server/32096374#32096374) (E1, E2, E4, Tally)

Comment: Your sql works beautifully, however, it needs also to include that record 17/09/2015 ║ Airn     ║ Casual       ║ Timesheet    in the result.

Comment: Also could you explain this part? WITH E1(N) AS(
    SELECT 1 FROM(VALUES
        (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1)
    )t(N)

Comment: Please see my update and the link to the explanation.

Comment: Perfect, I could successfully implement the query in my Stored Procedure with some adjusts... thanks

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use permanent [`Calendar`](http://web.archive.org/web/20150512230546/http://web.archive.org/web/20070611150639/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/why-should-i-consider-using-an-auxiliary-calendar-table.html) table for this type of queries, rather than generating a set of numbers on the fly. `Calendar` table is a special case of [table of numbers](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1).

For this query it is convenient to have a date and a flag `IsWeekday` in the `Calendar` table. I have few other fields in it in my database, see the links above for more details and ideas.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Calendar](
    [dt] [date] NOT NULL,
    [IsWeekday] [bit] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Calendar] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [dt] ASC
))
GO

-- Init calendar table with dates from 2000-01-01 till 2136-11-22 (50K rows)
INSERT INTO dbo.Calendar (dt, IsWeekday)
SELECT TOP (50000)
    DATEADD(day, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.[object_id])-1, '2000-01-01') AS dt
    , 1 AS IsWeekday
FROM sys.all_objects AS s1 CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS s2
OPTION (MAXDOP 1);

-- Set IsWeekday flag
UPDATE dbo.Calendar
SET IsWeekday = 0
WHERE ((DATEPART(weekday, dt) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7) IN (0, 1);
```

Now we are ready.
We'll find all permanent employees and generate a set of weekday dates for each permanent employee within the given range, then `LEFT JOIN` to it the original rows. This result will be unioned with the simple set of non-permanent employees.

Here is [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/37e03/6/0).

```
DECLARE @VarStartDate date = '2015-09-14';
DECLARE @VarEndDate date = '2015-09-20';
DECLARE @T TABLE (
    dt date, 
    Employee nvarchar(50), 
    EmployeeType varchar(50), 
    Tp varchar(50));

INSERT INTO @T (dt, Employee, EmployeeType, Tp) VALUES
('2015-09-14', 'John' , 'Permanent', 'Timesheet'),
('2015-09-14', 'Silva', 'Permanent', 'Timesheet'),
('2015-09-16', 'John' , 'Permanent', 'Timesheet'),
('2015-09-17', 'Airn' , 'Casual'   , 'Timesheet');

WITH
CTE_Employees
AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT Employee, EmployeeType
    FROM @T
    WHERE EmployeeType = 'Permanent'
)
,CTE_Dates
AS
(
    SELECT
        CTE_Employees.Employee
        ,CTE_Employees.EmployeeType
        , dbo.Calendar.dt
    FROM
        CTE_Employees
        CROSS JOIN dbo.Calendar
    WHERE
        dbo.Calendar.dt >= @VarStartDate AND
        dbo.Calendar.dt <= @VarEndDate AND
        dbo.Calendar.IsWeekday = 1
)
SELECT
    CTE_Dates.dt
    ,CTE_Dates.Employee
    ,CTE_Dates.EmployeeType
    ,ISNULL(T.Tp, 'Missing') AS Tp
FROM
    CTE_Dates
    LEFT JOIN @T AS T ON
        T.Employee = CTE_Dates.Employee AND
        T.dt = CTE_Dates.dt

UNION ALL

SELECT
    T.dt
    ,T.Employee
    ,T.EmployeeType
    ,T.Tp
FROM @T AS T
WHERE EmployeeType <> 'Permanent'

ORDER BY dt, Employee;
```

**Result**

```
dt            Employee    EmployeeType    Tp
2015-09-14    John        Permanent       Timesheet
2015-09-14    Silva       Permanent       Timesheet
2015-09-15    John        Permanent       Missing
2015-09-15    Silva       Permanent       Missing
2015-09-16    John        Permanent       Timesheet
2015-09-16    Silva       Permanent       Missing
2015-09-17    Airn        Casual          Timesheet
2015-09-17    John        Permanent       Missing
2015-09-17    Silva       Permanent       Missing
2015-09-18    John        Permanent       Missing
2015-09-18    Silva       Permanent       Missing
```

Comment: Amazing, both solutions are very good. I wish I could Set both as the best answer.