# SQL - Cumulative sum in sql, base on continuous dates

Tags: sql-server, cumulative-sum

Suppose I have a table with data as below:

```
SELECT *
FROM TestTable
ORDER BY deliver_date

deliver_date    quantity
2015-10-01  5.00
2015-10-02  3.00
2015-10-05  10.00
2015-10-07  8.00
2015-10-08  6.00
```

I know how to do the cumulative as below:

```
SELECT t1.deliver_date, SUM(t2.quantity) AS cumQTY 
FROM TestTable t1 
INNER JOIN TestTable t2 ON t2.deliver_date <= t1.deliver_date 
GROUP BY t1.deliver_date
ORDER BY t1.deliver_date
```

result:

```
deliver_date    cumQTY
2015-10-01  5.00
2015-10-02  8.00
2015-10-05  18.00
2015-10-07  26.00
2015-10-08  32.00
```

But, is it possible for me to get the result as below?

```
deliver_date    cumQTY
2015-10-01  5.00
2015-10-02  8.00
2015-10-03  8.00
2015-10-04  8.00
2015-10-05  18.00
2015-10-06  18.00
2015-10-07  26.00
2015-10-08  32.00
```

Means, the date must follow continuously.
For example: I do not have 2015-10-03 data in my TestTable table, but the cumulative table must show the date 2015-10-03

Appreciate if someone can help on this.
Thank you.

Comment: What version of sql-server are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using a [Tally Table](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/):

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1dedb/1/0)

```
DECLARE @startDate  DATE,
        @endDate    DATE

SELECT
    @startDate  = MIN(deliver_date),
    @endDate    = MAX(deliver_date)
FROM TestTable

;WITH E1(N) AS(
    SELECT 1 FROM(VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))t(N)
),
E2(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E1 a CROSS JOIN E1 b),
E4(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E2 a CROSS JOIN E2 b),
Tally(N) AS(
    SELECT TOP(DATEDIFF(DAY, @startDate, @endDate) + 1)
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM E4
),
CteAllDates AS(
    SELECT
        deliver_date = DATEADD(DAY, t.N-1, @startDate),
        quantity = ISNULL(tt.quantity, 0)
    FROM Tally t
    LEFT JOIN TestTable tt
        ON DATEADD(DAY, N-1, @startDate) = tt.deliver_date
)
SELECT
    deliver_date,
    cumQty = SUM(quantity) OVER(ORDER BY deliver_date)
FROM CteAllDates
```

---

First, you want to generate all dates starting from the `MIN(deliver_date)` up to `MAX(deliver_date)`. This is done using a tally table, the `CTE`s from `E1(N)` up to `Tally(N)`.

Now that you have all the dates, do a `LEFT JOIN` on the original table, `TestTable`, to get the corresponding `quantity`, assigning `0` if there is no matching dates.

Lastly, to get the cumulative sum, you can use `SUM(quantity) OVER(ORDER BY deliver_date)`.

---

*For more explanation on tally table, see my [answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32096374/2203084)*